# Issues rendering DataTables.net in MVC partial view after adding JSON calls

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm trying to use datatables and jeditable for my project to render an editable table on the screen. This is displayed in a partial view that is called by the index. However, when I try to load it, it loads shows the html of the page on the screen instead of rendering it. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong to fix this?

Here is my partial view:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="../../Scripts/FixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.jeditable.mini.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable1 = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '/Home/PartialView',
        "fnDrawCallback": function () {
            $('#myDataTable tbody td:nth-child(2)').editable('/Home/Write/', {
                "callback": function (sValue, y) {
                    oTable1.fnDraw();
                },


            });
        }
    });
})
</script>
<table id ="myDataTable" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Analysis ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Sample Type</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
            <th>Product ID</th>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Call to the partial view in my index:

```
  @if(ViewBag.SearchKey != null)
  {

     @Html.Action("PartialAnalysis", "Home", (string)ViewBag.SearchKey)

     {Html.RenderAction("PartialView", "Home", (string)ViewBag.SearchKey);}

   }
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult PartialView(jQueryDataTableParamModel param, string Search)
    {
        PartialModel D = new PartialModel();
        IEnumerable<PartialModel> model = D.SlagList;
        D.ViewDataPull(Search);

        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = D.List.Count(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = D.List.Count(),
            aaData = D.List
        },
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: have you checked to see that your AJAX call is not returning sanitized html instead of true html? sorry if that sounds too simplistic.

Comment: I think, you are taking it wrong. You should render a html markup for your whole table (including data rows)  (e.g. with that Action or Partial method) and then calling `datatable()` on that html table will make a jquery datatable from it. (When you return a `JsonResult` from your `PartialView` method you can only get the content of an Json object rendered - not the HTML table markup)

Comment: @iGanja When I look at it it appears to be returning a standard JSON array. This is my first time doing this, so I'm open to anything.